# How to select groups by condition occurring within a date range?

Tags: sas

I have data structured like this:

| ID | test_date | test_result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 27Mar1992 | N |
| 1 | 08Dec1999 | P |
| 1 | 29Jan2005 | N |
| 2 | 13Jan2015 | N |
| 2 | 09Mar2017 | P |
| 2 | 05Jun2018 | P |
| 3 | 15Oct1996 | N |
| 3 | 05Sep1997 | N |
| 3 | 28Jun1998 | N |

I need to keep all records for each ID if they had a test_result=P that occurred within 2017-2018. For this example only records from ID 2 would be kept.

Thank you!

Comment: can you use python to solve this problem?

Comment: So what did you try?  Please show your code.

Comment: I was able to count the total number of positive tests (test_result=P) for each id and merge that back to the original data, allowing me to delete records for ids that never had a positive test. But at that point I am stuck and don't know how to keep records for only ids that had a positive test between 2017 and 2018.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution if you were using python and pandas

Your data

`df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 3}, 'test_date': {0: '27Mar1992', 1: '08Dec1999', 2: '29Jan2005', 3: '13Jan2015', 4: '09Mar2017', 5: '05Jun2018', 6: '15Oct1996', 7: '05Sep1997', 8: '28Jun1998'}, 'test_result': {0: 'N', 1: 'P', 2: 'N', 3: 'N', 4: 'P', 5: 'P', 6: 'N', 7: 'N', 8: 'N'}} )`

This line of code implements your logic

`df.loc[df['test_date'].str.extract('(\d{4})')[0].astype(int).between(2017,2018) & df['test_result'].eq('P')]`

```
   ID  test_date test_result
4   2  09Mar2017           P
5   2  05Jun2018           P
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am using SAS

Answer (score 0):

A `SQL` query with a `having` clause will produce the result set.

```
data have;
input ID    test_date date9.    test_result $;
format test_date date9.;
datalines;
1   27Mar1992   N
1   08Dec1999   P
1   29Jan2005   N
2   13Jan2015   N
2   09Mar2017   P
2   05Jun2018   P
3   15Oct1996   N
3   05Sep1997   N
3   28Jun1998   N
;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select * from have
  group by id
  having sum (year(test_date)=2017 and test_result='P') > 0
  ;
```

Logs (remerge is special SAS `Proc SQL` feature)

```
56     ;
NOTE: The query requires remerging summary statistics back with the original data.
NOTE: Table WORK.WANT created, with 3 rows and 3 columns.
```

with result

[image]

Comment: That seems like it should work, but the output dataset has no rows. I know for a fact there are positive tests that occurred in 2017.

Comment: Updated with data, log and view. Double check your try, it indeed did work.